# Versión de SQL Server no es compatible

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

¿Porqué me aparece este error de `SQL Server`?:

> La versión de servidor no es compatible. El servidor de destino debe
>   ser SQL Server 2000 o posterior.

En estos momentos tengo instalado el SQL Server 2012, tengo el JDK 12 y JDBC creo que en la versión 4. Estoy tratando de crear una conexión con SQL Server.

**Código de conexión:**

```
Connection cn = null; 

try { 

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
    cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba;integratedSecurity=true"); 
    System.out.println("Conexion Exitosa"); } 

catch (Exception e) { //e.printStackTrace(); System.out.println("ERROR "+e.getMessage()); }
```

Comment: Pero que es lo que estas tratando de hacer?

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Estoy intentando conectarme a sqlserver

Comment: Ah ya veo mira aqui a esta persona le paso lo mismo http://www.forosdelweb.com/f45/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserver-921741/ tal vez te pueda funcionar

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Ya lo hize, y me sigue con el mismo error

Comment: No sabria que es entonces amigo lo siento

Comment: Publica el codigo que utilizas para conectarte a SQL.

Comment: y también el nombre del driver que estás usando, junto con otros detalles que creas que pueden ser de utilidad para reproducir tu escenario.

Comment: @Einer,@fredyfx este es el codigo                                         
 `Connection cn=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba;integratedSecurity=true");
            System.out.println("Conexion Exitosa");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERROR "+e.getMessage());
        }`

Comment: Modifica la pregunta y agrega la información del error ahí

Comment: Asegúrate que la version de los drivers JDBC sea 4 y no 3

Comment: Puedes comprobar la versión del driver usando: `SQLServerDriver drv = new SQLServerDriver(); System.out.println(drv.getMajorVersion() + "." + drv.getMinorVersion());`

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya lo pude solucionar,me faltaba colocarle el dll que permite la autorizacion por windows en el directorio del proyecto.